# Is it possible to break into interactive mode in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

If you run `node` you get into interactive mode, you can inspect, execute functions etc. But once you run a function from interactive mode or from the OS shell, can you pause execution and go to interactive mode deliberately?

In browser you can use `debugger` keyword, but in Node.js `debugger` does nothing for me.

Comment: Node.js has a built-in debugger.  I've had better luck though using WebStorm as its integration with Node.js' debugging port is solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When my software fails and I want to quickly figure it out, I add a `debugger` instruction where I want the debugger to break and do:

```
 node debug [script I want to debug]
```

Note that it is `node debug`, not `node --debug`. The latter also starts a debugger but it is one that waits on a port for some UI to connect.

Doing the above will cause the debugger to stop before executing your software. Type `c` to let it continue. It will next stop where you put your `debugger` statement. If you want to evaluate things dynamically you can use the `repl` command.

If you do it this way, you don't need any extra tools. The documentation is [here](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: yes! that's what I wanted, but now I cannot see local variables, any idea? only globals are visible from the gdb-style console

Comment: I generally have no problem. However, there's something that may be a bit confusing. Let's say you have variable ``x`` and that ``x``'s value is ``undefined``. So in the debugger you enter ``repl`` so get in repl-mode. Then you type ``x`` to evaluate ``x``. You won't get any feedback from the debugger that ``x``'s value is ``undefined``. When I suspect this is the case, I do ``console.log(x)``. The debugger is definitely rough around the edges but not needing any other tool is a win in my book.

Answer (score 2):

try the [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), you can debug your app with chrome developer tool

1.install and start node-inspector

```
npm install -g node-inspector
node-inspector &
```

2.start your app with debug parameter (if you want to break in the first line, replace the parameter to --debug-brk

```
node --debug server.js
```

3.open debug link in Chrome

```
open http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

[image]