# Google chrome "like" console inside Vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Looking for an extension or any way to load my current js file in the memory and play with it. Something similar to Google Chrome Console. let's say my terminal is on some folder, so as you know if I write `node file.js` this will execute the js file then the node process will terminate. I don't want that, I want to interact with the local variables of that file. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: yeah: start node in debug mode and break into its REPL (read-evaluate-print-loop) prompt so you can type things and have node evaluate it the same way the browser dev console works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to break into interactive mode in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500205/is-it-possible-to-break-into-interactive-mode-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are several ways you can that. Here are some of the ways I do it

1. For simple files (node.js), you can simple run the file using the debugger on vscode. The debugger icon is located on the left side of vscode (a bug with inside a terminating circle). You can look at the video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFtU6_UaOtA. If it doesn't help much, you can simple search online for articles and other videos.
2. For more complex app (an app with both server and client side rendering) and also simpler apps, you can use the `--inspect` flag on your start script and the use the chrome developer tool. You can look at this article or https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27 or look for similar once to help you with it.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently there is not a clean way to do it, but your approaches can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension: https://quokkajs.com/docs/

I was also looking for a solution to stop going back to Chrome to test simple functionalities and this tool seems to work very well.

[image]